# Apply "date tick labels" on seaborn chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to apply [date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) to my chart but the dates do not show up. There is no error messages so I guess the function cannot find the dates from my data.
For the final result I'd like to show ticks on the x-axis to mark each month but only show text (i.e. '2020-01') every 6 months.

Example

```
d = {'sel_date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 24).strftime('%Y-%m'), 'ID':list('abbb')*6, 'index':np.random.randint(10, size=24)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

```
sel_date    ID  index
0 2020-01   a   5
1 2020-01   b   1
2 2020-02   b   0
3 2020-02   b   2
4 2020-03   a   2
```

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
plot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='index', index=['sel_date'],
                    columns=['ID'], aggfunc=np.mean)
plot.fillna(0, inplace=True)

ax = sns.lineplot(data=plot)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

# Major ticks every 6 months.
fmt_half_year = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(fmt_half_year)

# Minor ticks every month.
fmt_month = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(fmt_month)
```

[image]

I'd like the chart's xticks in this style.
[image]

Comment: Don't do `.strftime('%Y-%m')`. You have to format the plot axis not the dataframe

Comment: And then follow the reset of the code at the [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have minor ticks every period and major ticks every six, then maybe this will help.

```py
# Import tick-locator instance
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

# Save pivoted data as `x`
x = pd.pivot_table(df, values='index', index='sel_date', columns='ID', aggfunc='mean')
x = x.fillna(0)

# Plot dates on x-axis and 'a' on y-axis
plt.plot(x.index, x['a'].values, ls='-', label='a')
# Plot dates on x-axis and 'b' on y-axis
plt.plot(x.index, x['b'].values, ls='--', label='b')
# Set minor ticks
plt.axes().xaxis.set_minor_locator(locator=MultipleLocator(1))
# Set major ticks
plt.axes().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator=MultipleLocator(6))
# Add legend and show
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]